# Python program to find text in page without using urllib2

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a python program that will look through a web page to find a specific text and if it finds the text, then it prints something out. If not, it prints out an error message. How can I achieve this without using urllib2 library?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do that. if you are looking for a fixed string, you can load all text into a variable `text` and then use `text.find('needle in the haystack')`. You can also use regular expressions with the `re` package in python. There is also `libxml` which can parse HTML.

Comment: Are you asking about alternative packages to urllib2?

Answer (score 1):

Use the requests library.

How to install it.

```
pip3 install requests
```

Here's an example of how to use it.

```
import requests

def get_webpage_html(url):
    return requests.get(url).text
```